# Split file based on lines

Tags: python, split, text-files, nosql

I have a very large text file (1.3 terabytes). The first 8 lines of this file is meta-information. I want to remove these lines and then import the rest of the files into a NoSQL database.

I am using this Python code:

```
fin = open( 'hugefile.vcf', "r" )
data_list = fin.readlines()
fin.close()
#remove lines
del data_list[0:7+1]
#write the changed data (list) to a file
fout = open("subset.vc", "w")
fout.writelines(data_list)
fout.close()
```

but the code is too slow.  It will take two weeks to finish its processing with 32 Gb RAM.

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You're not going to be able to read 1.3Tb into memory, so `readlines` is right out. You can skip 8 lines with `for _ in range(8): next(fin)`.

Comment: I would look at the Pool class in the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). This could potentially help you speed up your extraction.

Answer (score 1):

1.3Tb stuffed into 32Gb RAM gives you over 40x your memory size that needs to be swapped around as you  process the data, competing with the machine's other memory needs.  `jonrsharpe` gave you the gist: skip 8 lines with a trivial loop, then process the remaining lines individually.  Something like this:

```
fout = open("subset.vc", "w")
with open( 'hugefile.vcf', "r" ) as fin:
    # Ignore header lines
    for _ in range(8):
        next(fin)

    # Transfer data to output file
    for line in fin:
        fout.writeline(line)

fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is asking for a Python answer, but it may be cleaner to pipe through the classic Unix `tail` to skip the metadata and leave your Python code devoted to processing the data. E.g.

```
tail -n +8 hugefile.vcf | python code.py
```

The `-n` switch specifies where to start printing in number of lines relative to the end, but the `+` changes this behaviour to be relative to the beginning of the file, i.e. skip 8 lines.